# android how to solve layout design issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I try to make a chat application.I do not have enough experience in the design.So I have some problems.My problem seems on the picture below:
[image] 
and layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#0d8ec1" >
    
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/toImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toimage"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Ergin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/navBar"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="50dip"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_message"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
```

How can I solve problems in pictures?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Corrections in your xml. In your last `LinearLayout`, you have to remove `paddingBotton` and in your `EditText` and `Button` add the `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

So final result should be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/navBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0d8ec1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toimage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Ergin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toName"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navBar"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="50dip"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextButtonHoder">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextButtonHoder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:lines="3"
            android:minLines="3"
            >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

To explore the EditText take a look on this:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
/>
```

Comment: hi guy,This solved my centered problem.But I still have a problem.edittext is riding on message bubbles.

Comment: You can make the hight of you EditText fixed. and add a new tag in your listView. android:layout_above="LinearLayoutThatContainsTheEditText". For doing this you have to add an ID in your LinearLayout. I am updating My answer..

Answer (score 1):

Use your EditText and Enter button in RelativeLayout
and
Give property to both items as

```
android:centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: You have to define max lines in EditText otherwise it will overlap the screen if user enter multiple lines of text. most of the chat application provides max 4 lines which user can see.

Comment: how to keep a list of all messages on (edittext and button) ? thanks